# Java extended collection filtering

Tags: java, sorting, collections, filtering

I have to filter and  to sort a ArrayList wíth objects.
- Every object has **2** integer **pairs** => **4 ints per Object**.
- Every value of **Column_1 < Column_2** and
- Every value of **Column_3 < Column_4**.
... so each pair represents a distance.

1.) Distance in 1st(Column_1,Column_2) pair and 2nd(Column_3, Column_4,) pair have to be equal.

2.) if there exists in the list a Obj_1 , whose Column_2 value is equal to Column_1 value+1 of Obj_2 and

3.) if there exists in the list a Obj_1 , whose Column_4 value is equal to Column_3 value+1 of Obj_2

then this objects should be merged to one Object respecting values in each pair. ...minimal values in(Column_1,Column_3) and maximal values(Column_2,Column_4)

**Example:**

```
Column_1  Column_2  Column_3  Column_4
```

----------- before filtering --------------

```
1. 506       520     771       785
2. 106       110     210       214
3. 502       505     181       184
4. 714       717     270       273
5. 106       110     310       314
6. 111       115     215       219
7. 521       524     767       770
8. 502       505     350       353
9. 100       105     204       209
```

-----------after filtering----------

```
1. 100        115    204       219
2. 106        110    310       314
3. 502        505    181       184
4. 714        717    270       273
5. 502        520    767       785
```

How can this kind of filtering be done in Java?

Comment: Homework?  What have you tried?

Comment: not really! It's part of Informatic 2, thah I somehowe passed in college. It's my general problem with algorithms :-(. Maybe you have some usefull links for solving algorthmical problems!?

Comment: Don't flag your question for moderator attention unless you want it deleted.  That is, because you don't have enough rep to delete it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>My first approach would be to</strike>

1. implement `Comparable` (or write a `Comparator`) based on the logic described above,
2. write an `equals` method implementing the same logic,
3. fill the contents of the `ArrayList` into a `TreeSet`,
4. iterate over the set to merge adjacent elements when applicable.

The `TreeSet` will order its elements by natural ordering (or using a provided `Comparator`).

#### Refined approach

Unfortunately I failed to notice that distinct objects may contain overlapping intervals, thus items to be merged may not be adjacent. An improvement to the above could be:

1. implement `Comparable` based on Columns 1 and 3,
2. (write an `equals` method comparing all columns),
3. sort the contents of the `ArrayList`,
4. for each element in the list, search for elements fulfilling conditions 2) and 3) above, which can then be merged to the original element. Since the list is ordered, you can use binary search over the sublist *after* the current item. If the current element is merged with another, Columns 2 and 4 are updated, but 1 and 3 not, so the ordering does not change. The other element can then be removed from the list, and the search repeated with the new values of columns 2 & 4, for the sublist after the removed element.

Comment: One iteration won't be enough since there are two dimensions. I would suggest a tweak - for step 4, while iterating construct a new collection. Create a new data point using first elem of sorted collection. If next elem is contiguous extend the new data point. Otherwise push it to new collection and create new data point.

Comment: Thanks Peter!! You suggesting also Treeset it will automatically remove dublicates. When a element is duplicate, i have to explain in compareTo and equals methods, right?  
Here is my "preSolution" http://pastebin.com/RkUu0fuY.  But somehow don't right explanation for comparable, or at least right order of elements, can you check pls?

Comment: @jack, since that earlier version of my answer I have realized that removing duplicates is not the right solution here - you need to merge them (by hand). And you should remove the `-1`s from your `compareTo` implementation, otherwise it won't be correct (think "symmetricity" - i.e. `sgn(a.compareTo(b))` should be `-sgn(b.compareTo(a))`).

Comment: yeah, I am trying to merge two object. By looking for next objects  start-value those should be next following number of this.object end-value. How can I ohterwise compare two not equal objects!? Generally all objects/rows in the list are equal...

Comment: @jack, you should separate the order comparison from the detection of "adjacent" objects. The former is used for ordering the elements within the set, thus it must obey the constraints defined by the Java API. The latter should obey the rules defined above, in your post.

Comment: @peter, exactly at this point I am disordered. Points 1 and 2 in your approach responsible for comparison, right? And detection of "adjacents" happends in 4. during iteration over a TreeSet right? So having one object, I have to iterate over whole Set, then move to next one. Is this the only possible solution? There is no really use of Treeset in this case!?

Comment: @jack, now this boils down to your "specification" above, which is not 100% clear to me on second thought. My understanding is that for two objects to be merged, _both_ conditions 2) and 3) above must be fulfilled. If this is correct, you only need the right comparator for the job - TreeSet then orders the elements for you so that candidates for merge will be adjacent! Thus you only need to iterate over the set once.

Comment: @peter, yes conditions 1-3 above must be fullfilled. And yes this is the point I can't implement the right comparator with compare(),equals(),hash()-overridin. Because I never used comparable/comparator before. What I am doing wrong when describing, how can I describe this more clear!?

Comment: @jack, oops, just now I realized that one of my assumptions was wrong: I failed to notice that there are overlapping intervals between distinct items. So my comparator approach does not work :-( excuse me for the misleading ideas. I will think of an alternative approach...

Answer (score 1):

[Google collections](https://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) gives you the option to specify a filter predicate that will operate on all entries and decide which to preserve:

```
Collections2.filter(yourCollection, new Predicate<YourType>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(YourType param) {
    // return whether to retain or remove
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Bozho for this hint! Do you have a simple example or link how to implement this Predicate object... i didn't find any example..

Comment: well, you have your param (which is an element of the collection) - then go and implement your logic.

Comment: If I could implement, this logic with comparator or for Predicate in google collections2. I would't ask anybody and even write this post!!