# java comparator for simple custom logic

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

How I can find line 4,1 and 6 in example below?
And is the use of Collection.sort() with Comparator reasonable in this case?

```
       a -  b - c - d

1.)    6    8   16  18   
2.)    38  40   55  57  
3.)    6    8   25  27  
4.)    1    5   11  15  
5.)    6    8    3   5  
6.)    9   12   19  22   
7.)    18  20    1   3  
8.)    23  25   15  17
```

Example on the top is a List with object meets following criteria:
- every object contains 4 integer(a,b,c,d),
- every object in the list is unique,
- a < b and c < d.

---

Below is not working example, but my way of thinking, how I can expect comparator to work for finding expected object.

```
public class Row_Filter implements Comparable<Row_Filter>{
    int a,b,c,d;
    public Row_Filter(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
        this.a = a; this.b = b; this.c = c; this.d = d;
    }
   static class FilterAccordingAB implements Comparator<Row_Filter> {
        public int compare(Row_Filter o1, Row_Filter o2) {
            return o2.a - o1.b+1;
        }
    }
   static class FilterAccordingCD implements Comparator<Row_Filter> {
        public int compare(Row_Filter o1, Row_Filter o2) {
            return o2.c - o1.d+1;
        }
    }
   static class FilterAccordingABCD implements Comparator<Row_Filter> {
        public int compare(Row_Filter o1, Row_Filter o2) {
            FilterAccordingAB abF=null;    FilterAccordingCD cdF=null;
            if((abF.compare(o1, o2)==0) && (cdF.compare(o1, o2)==0)){
                return 1;
            }
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this happen to be homework?

Comment: What's special about lines 1,4 and 6?

Comment: what object types are you dealing with? ... so many questions means your question is a bad one!

Comment: Special, this are objects that i have to merge in my list to one single line/object -->(1 - 12 - 11 - 22).

Comment: @psanton: its generic object with 4 integer values. Question is not bad it seems to be difficult!? ;-)

Comment: For context, this is a follow-up to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712669/java-extended-collection-filtering

Comment: Line 5 also has four unique values with a<b and c<d. Did you mean a<b<c<d?

Comment: Comparator classes don't find things, they compare things.

Comment: Have you looked at the Java Docks for the Comparator interface?  I would start there.  What code have you written?  Where are you stuck?  We don't want to do your work for you, but we are more than happy to help if you are stuck with something not working.

Comment: @DJClayworth: Ok thank you, maybe you have still one idea how i can define, comparator that delivers me a true result for comparing line 1 and 4??

Comment: @jackdaniels You still haven't told us what it is about lines 1 and 4 that make you want them to compare 'equal' while other lines compare 'unequal'. Or are you just wanting to know how to write a Comparator in general?

Comment: @DJClayworth: only a line like a==b==c==d wouldn't be unique. And there is no condition like a<b<c<d. Between a<b and c<d is only one condition they have to have the same interval (b-a)==(d-c). But this is already made every object in the list meets this criteria.

Comment: @pstanton: No Anton this is not a riddle, it just a real question how to find this rows with help of java prog-language. Sorry if it sounds to much dumb..

Comment: @aperkins: Yes I looked at the Javadocs and comb trough many examples. But describes only the way how to compare equal/not equal values. However many professionals suggesting to use comparable/comparator. My way to find this rows is, 
1.) compare values of obj1.b and obj2.a and obj1.d and obj2.c. And then in 2nd step.. If obj1.b == obj2.a-1 and obj1.d == obj2.c-1, then I can merge this object.  
My Question was just about, how to define this logic with help of comparator.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is implement a Comparator **interface**. Look up the JavaDocs for that interface. You will need to write a class that **implements** that interface. This involves writing one method (you don't need to reimplement equals()).

The method gets passed two objects. Look at what value you need to return from the method to show the two objects are 'equal' according to your requirements. Then write the code to return that value when they are 'equal', according to your requirements.

If any of that is unclear you will need to look up a basic Java textbook on writing methods, writing classes or using interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are confused where you would use a comparator.  DJClayworth describes exactly HOW to create one.  You would use one in, for instance, a sort mechanism:

```
Collections.sort(myList, myComparator);
```

You use this because you can define the comparison algorithm to sort through the collection.  Hope this helps clarify somewhat.

Comment: Thank you Aperkins. I am not really confused where to use comparator (in case of List).  But, how to describe matching criteria to  comparator in Comparator-Language.

Comment: Really confused I become, if thinking about how to reduce list size by merging objects. By Folowing this way, I have to create 2nd list,  iterating  through 1st list coping values of matched object and calling by every match Collection.sort() method. For larger list this seems not to be a perfomant solution. If somebody is intersted below is a link for initial description of entire problem. Link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712669/java-extended-collection-filtering